# Opening less connections with rethinkDB

Tags: node.js, rethinkdb

My question is; Can i have less connections open when using rethindb? Right now I'm opening a new one every time I want to insert or get some data. Im afraid that this is not a right thing to do. Is there any way I can open just one and use it instead? I'm using nodejs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You can run multiple queries on a connection.  That's the recommended way of doing things.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use connection pool. For nodejs, for example, we are using [rethinkdb-pool](https://github.com/hden/rethinkdb-pool).

Answer (score 0):

I havent looked into the opensource connection pools for rethink, but I have a node app that uses rethink, and it will have a limited number of users, So I save my one connection to rethink as a global var and then use it for all queries.

```
'use strict';
var r = require('rethinkdb);
var rethinkConnect = null;
r.connect(
    {
        'host': 'localhost',
        'port': '28015',
        'password': 'noneya',
    },
    function(err, conn) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            rethinkConnect = conn;
        }
    }
);
```

Now all queries the node.js server makes can use the connection. Keep in mind this code is async so you could not immediately make a query the next line after `r.connect()`. You could, however, use the payload of an inbound `socket.io` event as the params of a rethink query.

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise you to use [rethinkdbdash](https://github.com/neumino/rethinkdbdash), an "advanced Node.js RethinkDB driver" that includes connection pools and some other advanced features. It has many more stars and contributors than rethinkdb-pool.